# AngularJs controller value doesn't update after factory resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I'm trying to build a user page where it shows it's main data, details, address, etc.. When I make the first load, it doesn't show on the screen until I change the page and go back to the user page. It's problaby because of the promise return after I already went to that page.

I can't (don't want to) use this data to be loaded during the `resolve` on the `stateChange` because it make the app feels freezing, since it will only change screen after all the data is `resolved`, and if it take some time, it seems the page isn't working.

I also tried using `$scope.$digest()` (on the `controller`) and `$rootScope.$apply()` on the `factory`, but both situations give me the `digest running` error.

Using `.then()` isn't an option (unless there is a proper way) because if I'm returning to that page after the first load, there will be errors.

The way I'm loading this is from a `parent` (abstract) `controller` and storing those values in a `factory`, something like this:

```
//Parent Controller
function parentController(requestFactory, storeFactory, $q) {
    var
        user = storeFactory.userGet(),
        data = storeFactory.dataGet()
        [...more load...];

    if(!user || !data ...) {
        var promises = {
            user:    requestFactory.get('userGet'),
            data:    requestFactory.get('dataGet'),
            [...more requests...]
        };

        return $q.all(promises).then(function(resolve){
            storeFactory.userAdd(resolve.user);
            storeFactory.dataAdd(resolve.data);
            [...more update...]
        });
    }
}

//Factory
function storeFactory() {
    var 
        data    = null,
        user    = null,
        address = null,
        endereco = null;

    var service = {
        userGet: _userGet,
        userAdd: _userAdd,
        [...more definitions...]
    };
    return service;


    function _userGet() {
        return user;
    }
    function _userAdd(data) {
        return user = data;
    }
    [...more functions...]
}

// child Controller 01
function child1Controller(storeFactory) {
    vm.user = storeFactory.userGet();
}

// child Controller 02
function child2Controller(storeFactory) {
    vm.address = storeFactory.addressGet();
}
```

I also need to load all these data on the beginning because there is dependent data, for example, the address depends on the user, etc..

---

So, if I access the page **user > address** it's not showing anything on the screen, but if I go to other page and came back, everything will show like it's supposed to show.

Is there a way to solve this problem? To make the data update automatically?

Comment: If you are using ui-router, you can make promises resolve before the state transition happens, so the data will be there. Otherwise, just wait for the promises to resolve in the controller and update the UI accordingly

Comment: @reptilicus But I dont want to use it in the ui-router resolve because it feels the page isn't working, since it will only change AFTER the data is resolved, wich can take some time. When using the resolve on the controller, I' m with problems to update the ui after the resolve.

Comment: Well if you are waiting for lots of promises to resolve, then yeah, its going to take a while. Either break up the promises into groups that can be used to update the UI or find a way to make less requests?

Comment: @reptilicus but isn't there a way to update it after the resolves? Like we can do with  `$digest()`?

Comment: If there is data bound from the service calls, then it will update automatically. You do not need to call $digest or $apply if it is bound to $scope in the templates.

Comment: @reptilicus it starts as nulls, as show in the factory step, and im using vm syntax (but I dont think it's a problem). So I would need to start using any vakid data instead of null or undefinied? im not on the computer right now, but will test soon

Comment: @reptilicus I tried setting the variables with a start value, but nothing happens, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I could solve this problem, was to create a single object with nested arrays in the factory, instead of creating multiple arrays. Also, in the controller, I can't set the specific array direct to the vm, I need to set the array inside the object, this way it's automatically updated.

```
//Factory
var data = {
    user: null,
    address: null,
    [...]
};

function _userAdd(value) {
    return data.user = value;
}
[...etc...]

//Controller
function child1Controller(storeFactory) {
    vm.maindata = storeFactory.data;
}
```

After doing this, I need to specify the nested array on the view, like this:

```
<p>{{vm.maindata.user}}</p>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="address in vm.maindata.address track by $index">{{address}}</li>
</ul>
```

---

Even though it's working, it doesn't feel like the right way to do, so, if there is a better way to achieve this result, I'm open to suggestions.